# Local notification sound not working

Tags: ios, swift, audio, ios8, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to make an alarm app but when I try to make a local notification I am unable to play the sound. I got this error:

`[user info = (null)} with a sound but haven't received permission from the user to play sounds]`

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var setAlaram: UIDatePicker!


@IBAction func setAlarmButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var dateformater = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformater.timeZone = NSTimeZone .defaultTimeZone()
    dateformater.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateformater.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var datetimestring = NSString()
    datetimestring = dateformater.stringFromDate(setAlaram.date)
    println(datetimestring)

    [self .localnotification(setAlaram.date)]

}

func localnotification (firedate:NSDate)  {

    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = firedate
    localNotification.alertBody = "time to woke up"
    localNotification.soundName = "alarm.wav"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let date1 = NSDate()
    setAlaram.date = date1

}
```

Comment: the usage of `localnotification` as a *function* name is somewhat confusing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to ask the user for permission to send local notifications in iOS 8.

You can do so when you application launches in your AppDelegate methods

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil))
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help now i'm getting notification but not playing sound ?

Comment: Is that sound you have custom?

Comment: My suggestion is set `localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` and see if the sound works. If it does then you know it is your custom sound.

Comment: i found the solution its working on real device not on simulator still i can use localNotification.soundName = "alarm.wav" but thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Posting the final answer with the help of sbarow i found the solution here is the code it may be helpful for others.

1.**AppDelegate.swift** replace this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil))
    return true
}
```

2.**ViewController.swift:**

```
@IBOutlet var setAlaram: UIDatePicker!


@IBAction func setAlarmButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var dateformater = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformater.timeZone = NSTimeZone .defaultTimeZone()
    dateformater.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateformater.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var datetimestring = NSString()
    datetimestring = dateformater.stringFromDate(setAlaram.date)
    println(datetimestring)

    [self .localnotification(setAlaram.date)]
}

func localnotification (firedate:NSDate)  {
    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = firedate
    localNotification.alertBody = "time to woke up"
    localNotification.soundName = "alarm.wav"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let date1 = NSDate()
    setAlaram.date = date1
}
```